# Is it OK not to call Thread#join?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

Is it OK not to call `Thread#join`? In this case, I don't care if the thread blows up - I just want Unicorn to keep processing.

```
class MyMiddleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    t = Thread.new { sleep 1 }
    t.join # is it ok if I skip this?
    @app.call env
  end
end
```

Will I get "zombie threads" or something like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's perfectly fine to not call `join` - in fact, `join` is often not needed at all with multithreaded code.  You should only call `join` if you need to block until the new thread completes.

You won't get a "zombie" thread.  The new thread will run until completion, then clean itself up for you.

Comment: I agree, join is incredibly overrated. It's useful early when you're teaching people about threads, but once you get to understand how threads really work, you realize joins really limit your ability to multithread effectively. A pattern I notice is that joins usually only get used on very short-lived threads, like worker threads. Example: manager thread spawns 10 worker threads, then joins them all, gathers their results and processes it.

Comment: @glowcoder Exactly - and, often, there are better options than join in those situations, depending on the platform and libraries you're using...